# iOS8 touch previous controller's events still called

Tags: ios, ios8

I have two views.
The main view has touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded functions.
I am calling NSLog in these methods.

Then, I call a second view with performSegueWithIdentifier which is set to Show Detail
(But I have tried other options as well).

The problem is that when the second view is on the foreground, it seems all the touch events are still logged and the main controller is receiving the touch events.

How can I make it so that the main controller will respond to touch events only when it is on the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the UIViewController from the stack ?
or try to handle your methods in

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Do you're thing here
 }
```

im not sure how you do it in Swift.